# How to install conda package manager only?

Tags: software-installation

How to install only conda and its dependencies? Since I already have Python I don't want to install anaconda or miniconda. What I need is only and only conda package manager and its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your objection to it: install miniconda. miniconda only installs conda and its dependencies so that would satisfy your needs. The fact you already have python installed has not a lot to do with installing conda: "during the installation you need to  add the conda installation of Python to your PATH environment variable nothing more".

Also see the [installation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) guide for conda.

Comment: "during the installation you need to add the conda installation of Python to your PATH environment variable nothing more"- What does this line means . I can't understand. Please explain. Will it install Python twice or the previously installed Python will be used.

Comment: During installation of conda you tell it where to find python. "will it install Python twice" of course not :P

Comment: How do that? I mean how to tell where to find Python.